# How should I make a system-wide dialog for Windows 8?

Tags: dialog, windows-8

I have an application that presents a dialog to the user. This dialog must be dealt with within a few seconds (it is to allow or deny a connection to the computer).

In Windows 7 this is not a problem: I present a dialog (without stealing focus) that displays on top of all other windows. However in Windows 8, this dialog is only visible on the desktop. If the user is on the Metro Start Screen, or in another app, the dialog is invisible.

How should I display a system-wide dialog in Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display a system wide notification from a Metro style app you'll want to use the new Toast notification mechanism in WinRT.  (See below)

If you want to display system wide notifications from a desktop app, that is still TBD.  (Microsoft might allow you to use the toast notifications WinRT api from desktop apps)

---

### Toast notifications

A toast notification is a transient message to the user that contains relevant, time-sensitive information and provides quick access the subject of that content in an app. It can appear whether you are in another app, the Start screen, or on the desktop. Toasts are an optional part of the app experience and are intended to be used only when your app is not the active foreground app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465385.aspx
(Scroll to the middle of the page)